# Security Rule to 'not grant permission' to create new sheet in Particular app in qliksense

Tags: security, qliksense

I have created an App in qliksense server, with many sheets in it.Now i want to create security rule for the app so that no more sheets are created by others except me.How could be done this.Please help me in this.